# Conditionals with past perfect

Tags: conditional-perfect

Can I use past perfect in conditional sentence?

Is this phrase correct?

> She could have helped him would she had known something about first aid.

If this is a complicated situation, how you feel about it? (kludgy/strange/etc). Thanks.

Comment: I think it would parse easier if you swapped it around "Would that she had known something about first aid, she could have helped him."

Comment: I would write, "She could have helped him, had she known something about first aid." The "could" is enough of a conditional; "would" seems out of place. You could swap the clauses as @KitZ.Fox suggests, but then I would turn it into two sentences, punctuated as follows: "Would that she had known something about first aid! She could have helped him."

Comment: @DavidK, ok, thanks. But question is: can I use 'would .. had ..third_form'? It this grammatically correct? thnx.

Comment: OP's example is a mangled version of a valid construction along the lines of *She could have helped him **if she'd have known** something about first aid*. Which is syntactically fine by me, but personally I don't like that usage where the conditional *if **she'd** have [pp]* is fully expanded to *if **she would** have [pp]*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. The inversion for a conditional clause is only used, in my experience, for a traditional clause with a so-called "past subjunctive" (the same as the simple past for every English verb except for *were*) of the auxiliary: *had*, *were*, *could*, *should*, and sometimes *did*:

So

> "Had I known, ..." = "If I had known, ..."
>
> "Were he to ask, ... " = "If he were to ask, ... "
>
> ?"Did they but try, ..." = "If they tried, ..." (I've put a query because this one is marginal, and to my ear it requires "but" to be grammatical).
>
> "Should he ask, ..." = "If he should ask, ... " (= "If he happens to ask")

The recent use of "would" for conditionals (which only some people use: I don't use it myself) does not allow inversion:

> "If I would have known, ... ", but not "Would I have known, ..."